# Access Denied when trying to run WSL bash.exe as system user (via a service)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to manage a service running inside WSL via a wrapper service running on Windows. But when I try to run the wrapper Windows service (which by default run as the "System" user, it throws an "Access Denied" error.

Same service when run as a **normal Admin user works fine**.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this and make it possible to run bash.exe as the "System" user? Or is that way by design and should be avoided?

Note: I use the following go code to run the WSL service. (I build this command into an exe and install it on Windows as a service using winsw)

```
exec.Command("bash.exe", "-c", "sudo /bin/bash service my-linux-service start")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue today,
I'm using NSSM to setup Windows services and I manage to sort things out by
setting the objectName to the current user for this service.
Now my service is executed by a user that can access WSL :

```
nssm set <servicename> ObjectName <username> <password>
```

Note: `<username>` should exactly be the output of `whoami.exe`

See [NSSM Documentation](http://nssm.cc/commands#exceptions) for more info.